# The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts error in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I want to execute this query :

```
public List<ViewSheet> ShowSheet(List<Sheet> lst)
{
   var res = (from sheet in _sheetRepository.Get()
       join line in _lineRepository.Get() on sheet.LineId equals line.Id
       join basemat in _baseMaterialRepository.Get() on sheet.BaseMaterialId equals basemat.Id
       join lineend in _lineEndRepository.Get() on sheet.LineEndId equals lineend.Id
       join Paint in _paintCodeRepository.Get() on sheet.PaintCodeId equals Paint.Id 
       select new ViewSheet()
       {
           BaseMaterialId = basemat.Name,
           Catagory = sheet.Catagory,

           LineEndId = lineend.Name,
           LineId = line.LineNumber,
           MtPercent = sheet.MtPercent,
           PAndId = sheet.PAndId,
           PaintCodeId = Paint.Name,
           ParentId = sheet.ParentId,

       }).ToList();
   return res;
}
```

as you can see i create a join between 4 tables and the `get` function has this structure :

```
public interface ISheetRepository
{
    IQueryable<Sheet> Get();
    bool Save();       
}
```

But i get this error :

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine in one query data retrieved from multiple contexts, these multiple contexts may point to two difference databases or have different options, then the query might not execute.

It seems that each repository creates its own `DataContext` object and retrieves the data using that object.

To solve that without have to pass the context and share it between all repositories, you might want to return a List from the `Get()` method and not an `IQueryable`. I don't know if you think that `Get()` is executing the query but it is not. It is just storing information about the query in `IQueryable`. Only when you call `.ToList();` inside your `ShowSheet` method, the queries of `Get()` gets executed.

Else, you need to create one context and use it in all the repositories in this query. Your option here is to have the constructor of the repository (or the `Get()` Method itself) accept a `YourContext` parameter. Then you pass the context : `_sheetRepository.Get(context)` so that all of them share the same object.