# How generate single UNION query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, union

I try to generate `UNION` query in LINQ:

```
var a = _aReposytory.GetAll().OrderByDescending(t => t.EndT).Take(100);
var b = _bReposytory.GetAll().OrderByDescending(t => t.EndT).Take(100);
var c = _cReposytory.GetAll().OrderByDescending(t => t.EndT).Take(100);
var d = _dReposytory.GetAll().OrderByDescending(t => t.EndT).Take(100);

var result = a.Cast<IEntity>().Union(b.Cast<IEntity>())
                .Union(c.Cast<IEntity>()).Union(d.Cast<IEntity>()).ToList();
```

All entityes inherit `IEntity` interface and has same fields. `_aReposytory.GetAll()`, `_bReposytory.GetAll()` etc return `IQueryable<T>`.   But i get error when trying get result.

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

It is works when i using folowing `UNION` logic. But it is four queries execution.

```
var union = new List<ICdcEntity>(a);
                union.AddRange(b);
                union.AddRange(c);
                union.AddRange(d);
```

How generate single `UNION` query in LINQ?

Comment: Does `_aReposytory.GetAll()` (and the other methods) return `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: Your error message is very clear. Every context generates SQL from your Linq query, but you cannot generate a single SQL statement from 4 different contexts. Even if you could, it would result in four queries anyway.

Comment: I believe the answer here properly explains your error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627389/3042383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework (or something similar) to fetch data from a database, you can choose to let your database perform the query, and return only the data you want, or you can choose to fetch more data than you want in your end result and filter it in local memory.

The first is done `AsQueryable`, the latter is done `AsEnumerable`.

Although [Queryable.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) exists, it can only unite tables that are in the same database.

You are performing the query on different repositories, this means that potentially their data might be in different databases.

If you want' to perform your union this way, you'll have to do it in local memory. [Enumerable.AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx) will bring your data to local memory, where it can be united with other data that is in local memory.

However, if your data is really supposed to be in the same database, then it would be much more efficient if you could perform your query AsQueryable. You should make certain that your repositories use the same instance of `DbContext`. In that case you should be able to perform your queries on database sid.

By the way, if you are doing this kine of uniting often, consider putting this into one unit-of-work using the unit-of-work pattern.

More information: [Implementing the repository pattern and unit-of-work patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a unified class and populate all the attributes in the select clause in each query and then do a Union.